# troubles with osm2pgrouting

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, query, osm2pgrouting

I'm trying desperately to write my first query in pgRouting using maps in osm format (as shown in http://www.carsonfarmer.com/?p=799).

Im using Ubuntu 10.10 with Postgresql 8.4 ang postgis 1.5.
After adding pgrouting functionality to my database and run osm2pgrouting command:

```
./osm2pgrouting -file /home/cfarmer/Downloads/ireland.osm -conf mapconfig.xml -dbname routing -user postgres -clean -passwd myPW
```

I get this message (that looks to be correct):

```
connection success
Trying to load config file mapconfig.xml
Trying to parse config
```

and I was expecting to find in my base tables such as ways, but I see only geometry_columns and saptial_ref_sys. 
Moreover when I try to run the query:

```
select * from shortest_path
        ('select gid as id,
            source::int4,
            target::int4,
            length::double precision as cost
            from ways',
        52343, 39219, false, false);
```

I get this error: errore di sintassi vicino il simbolo non atteso "from".
If I run the same query on pgAdmin I get a more specific error i.e.:
relation "ways" does not exist.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot
Laura

---

```
postgres@laura-VirtualBox:/home/laura$ cd /usr/bin
postgres@laura-VirtualBox:/usr/bin$ ./osm2pgrouting -file /home/laura/Scaricati/ireland.osm -conf mapconfig.xml -dbname routing -user postgres -passwd laura -clean
host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres dbname=routing port=5432 password=laura
connection success
Trying to load config file mapconfig.xml
Trying to parse config
postgres@laura-VirtualBox:/usr/bin$ select * from shortest_path ('select gid as id,source::int4,target::int4,length::double precision as cost from ways', 52343, 39219, false, false);
bash: errore di sintassi vicino il simbolo non atteso "from"
postgres@laura-VirtualBox:/usr/bin$ psql -U postgres routing
psql (8.4.8)
Digita "help" per aiuto.

routing=# select * from shortest_path ('select gid as id,source::int4,target::int4,length::double precision as cost from ways', 52343, 39219, false, false);
ERROR:  relation "ways" does not exist
RIGA 1: ...int4,target::int4,length::double precision as cost from ways
                                                               ^
QUERY: select gid as id,source::int4,target::int4,length::double precision as cost from ways
routing=#
```

Comment: I doubt your home location is "/home/cfarmer/". The OSM data most certainly wasn't loaded successfully.

Comment: Infact my home location was /home/laura, I pasted there from a tutorial, but I wrote it correctly on my shell. In the next comment I will paste my shell:

Comment: Still, if you can't see any tables loaded then your problem is not the pgRouting query.

Comment: No I can't see them!

Comment: Ok, so it's an osm2pgrouting problem.

Comment: how can I solve it?

Comment: have the sqls loaded correctly? routing_core.sql routing, routing_core_wrappers.sql , routing_topology.sql routing, routing_tsp.sql routing, routing_tsp_wrappers.sql , routing_dd.sql routing & routing_dd_wrappers.sql routing? then you can add your data to the database.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your mapconfig.xml is ok? There is a good tutorial on: http://download.osgeo.org/pgrouting/foss4g2010/workshop/docs/html/chapters/osm2pgrouting.html

Comment: How can I verify it is ok?

Comment: I was wondering if I should write his absolute path

Comment: It hasn't finished yet (it should be a good omen) but it is showing since (abuot) 40 minutes ago this message: "Classes table created". It is working right, isn't it?